# How to create multi Sub-Report with multi page using C# and Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

```
DataSet mdsData = new DataSet("Dosage");

        DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);

        AddTableToDataset(mdsData);

        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();

        rpt.Load("Report/rptMulti.rpt");
        mdsData.Tables.Add(table);
        //mdsData.Tables.Add(table1);
        mdsData.WriteXmlSchema("Schema/Dosage.xsd");


        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section sec = rpt.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.ReportHeaderArea.Sections[0];
        rpt.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreportEx("test1", "Report/6x10.rpt", sec, 100, 100, 7900, 5400);
        rpt.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreportEx("test2", "Report/6x10.rpt", sec, 8080, 100, 7900, 5400);
        rpt.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreportEx("test3", "Report/6x10.rpt", sec, 100, 5550, 7900, 5400);
        rpt.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreportEx("test4", "Report/6x10.rpt", sec, 8070, 5550, 7900, 5400);


        rpt.Subreports["test1"].SetDataSource(mdsData.Tables["table"]);
        rpt.Subreports["test2"].SetDataSource(mdsData.Tables["table"]);
        rpt.Subreports["test3"].SetDataSource(mdsData.Tables["table"]);
        rpt.Subreports["test4"].SetDataSource(mdsData.Tables["table"]);

        frmView _frmReportMulti = new frmView(table, "VIE");
        _frmReportMulti.Show();
        _frmReportMulti.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

[report viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmee7.png)

This is code that i create subreport and set postion on main report.
Currently i can just create multi subreport on one page,
I would like to create multi Subreport on multi page,

Please help me get ideas

Comment: can you explain what is multiple sub report on multiple pages?

Comment: Hi Siva, i have a subreport and have many Datatable, i want to use Datatables to create many subreport. but one page don't enough place

Comment: once you create a report or a sub report size depends on number of records that report is fetching and displaying...do you really want to limit the size of the report and how many records does a report fetch and display?

Comment: Yes, i want to limit the size of  the report, there are 6 records i want display, but one page don't enough